# why insert statement not working in postgres trying to insert json?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Why my insert statement not working?

here is my code
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17

```
create table json_check (
  id serial primary key not null ,
  body jsonb
)

insert into json_check (body)
values ('{

"test":"naveeb",
"data":"{'a':'ss'}"}')
```

It is showing me a syntax error.

Comment: Maybe, you need to escape the single and double quotes, like this `\"` and `\'`.

Comment: Also, General sql syntax for create table should be `create table json_check (
  id serial not null ,
  body jsonb, primary key \`id\`
)`. Not sure, if postgres have added support to declare primary key in column definition itself.

Comment: @Krishna: the syntax is perfectly valid and the primary **will** be created. Note that those dreaded backticks are invalid in Postgres (and SQL in general). And double quotes don't need to be escaped at all in SQL and single quotes are not escaped with a backslash but by doubling them in SQL

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your JSON  is invalid.

```
insert into json_check (body)
values ('{
    "test": "naveeb",
    "data": {
        "a": "ss"
    }
}');
```

You can check your JSON status on https://jsonlint.com/.

Running example pasted on below link:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/80ca3/6